# "Allow access to Azure services" turn off by default from ARM template

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-rm-template

Does anybody know how to setup ARM Template to keep "Allow access to Azure services" switch be turned OFF by default?
[image]

Here is what I currently have

```
 "resources": [
{
  "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
  "properties": {
    "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
    "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
    "version": "[parameters('serverVersion')]"
  },
  "tags": {
    "deploymentVersion": "[parameters('deploymentVersion')]",
    "deploymentType": "[parameters('deploymentType')]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
      ],
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
      "properties": {
        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
      },
      "type": "firewallrules"
    }
  ]
}  ]
```

Comment: Can you try by getting rid of `{
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
      ],
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
      "properties": {
        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
      },
      "type": "firewallrules"
    }`? This is where `Allow access to Azure services` firewall rule is set.

Comment: @GauravMantri it didn't help. The switch in the portal is still turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just modify `endIpAddress` and `startIpAddress` to `255.255.255.255`. Like below:

```
 {
                    "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
                    ],
                    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
                    "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
                    "properties": {
                        "endIpAddress": "255.255.255.255",
                        "startIpAddress": "255.255.255.255"
                    },
                    "type": "firewallrules"
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the nested `resources` section. Then the sql will deploy without that checkmark. Redeploying won't remove the rule, but deploying a new sql will work.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is when you use the name *AllowAllWindowsAzureIps* for a firewall resource type then it will ignore what range you specifiy in properties and just turn *Allow Access to Azure Services* flag on.

If you want to not have it enabled then don't include a resource with that name in your template.

Comment: This seems to hold true. I've been using IPs of 0.0.0.0 and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bicep example:

```
resource sqlServer 'Microsoft.Sql/servers@2022-02-01-preview' = {
  name: name
  location: location
  tags: tags
  properties: {
    administratorLogin: sqlAdministratorLogin
    administratorLoginPassword: sqlAdministratorLoginPassword
    version: '12.0'
  }
}

resource allowAccessToAzureServices 'Microsoft.Sql/servers/firewallRules@2020-11-01-preview' = {
  name: 'allow-access-to-azure-services'
  parent: sqlServer
  properties: {
    startIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
    endIpAddress: '0.0.0.0'
  }
}
```